# How to assign an array to a variable of a sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

I wish to assign a query result ("A") as an array into a customized variable of another query ("B"). I realize array variable is not allowed in sql so I wish to do it in JSON.
  Here are the example:

```
Query Result A:
Staff ID | Mariage status | Kids Details |
I022144  | yes            |              |
I062541  | yes            |              |
I322411  | yes            |              |
I445211  | no             |              |
D235544  | yes            |              |

Query Result B:
Staff ID | Kids Name      | Kids Gender  | Kids Age  |
I022144  | Pete           | M            | 3          |
I022144  | Sarah          | F            | 5          |
I062541  | Don            | M            | 10         |
I322411  | Keith          | M            | 9          |
D235544  | John           | M            | 2          |
D235544  | Nancy          | F            | 13         |
D235544  | Don            | M            | 1          |
```

Expected result in JSON

```
Dataset: [
  {"Staff ID": I022144, "Mariage status": yes, "Kids Details": [{"Kids Name": Pete, "Kids Gender": M, "Kids Age": 3}, {"Kids Name": Sarah, "Kids Gender": F, "Kids Age": 5}]},
  {"Staff ID": I062541, "Mariage status": yes, "Kids Details": [{"Kids Name": Don, "Kids Gender": M, "Kids Age": 10}]},
  {"Staff ID": I322411, "Mariage status": yes, "Kids Details": [{"Kids Name": Keith, "Kids Gender": M, "Kids Age": 9}]},
  {"Staff ID": I445211, "Mariage status": no, "Kids Details": []},
  {"Staff ID": D235544, "Mariage status": yes, "Kids Details": [{"Kids Name": John, "Kids Gender": M, "Kids Age": 2}, {"Kids Name": Nancy, "Kids Gender": F, "Kids Age": 13}, {"Kids Name": Don, "Kids Gender": M, "Kids Age": 1}]}
]
```

Appreciate your guidence. :)

Chappy

Comment: json_encode? http://php.net/manual/it/function.json-encode.php . Perform the query on A, push that into an array, use json_encode passing the array and the returned string should be what you're looking for, if I've got what you want to do :P

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My follow up question is since assigning result B to "Kids Details" in result A depends on Staff ID. How could I add a condition to check that when A."Staff ID" = B."Staff ID" then A."Kids Details" => {B."Kids Name", B."Kids Gender", B."Kids Age"} ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's exactly what you want to do.. Moreover I don't seen any code you've tried yet. Mine is just an idea but, if I've got what you want to do, it should be quite easy for you at this point to accomplish what you need. If you want to store the values into the database, however, please be aware that json strings are quite big, therefore don't forget to make a proper table in order to store them correctly :). edit: also, obviously, don't forget to **escape** them first ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You actualy can use array variables in SQL, You can do this
DECLARE @TableVariableName TABLE(
IDs VARCHAR(100),
numbers Int
);
Insert into @TableVariableName
 -----Do the select you want it to store it into the new table for example:
Select IDs,numbers from tbl1
```

Then you can use this table in another query as follow:

```
Select tbl2.column1, @TableVariableName.IDs, @TableVariableName.numbers from tbl2
join @TableVariableName ON tbl2.IDs = @TableVariableName.IDs
```

There you go. hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Alex. However, it seems your suggestion will result in a flattened table. I just wish that column "Kids Details" is an array. I think what briosheje suggested would fit more.